# RDS 2012 R2: Broker HA round-robin-name fails

Tags: windows-server-2012, remote-desktop, windows-server-2012-r2

I have these servers...

```
Name : DC1
Roles: PDC, File/Print, RD License, SQL 2012

Name : DC2 
Roles: BDC, RD Webaccess

Name : SVRDS1
Roles: RD Broker (primary), RD Host session

Name : SVRDS2
Roles: RD Broker, RD Host session

Name : SVRDS3
Roles: RD Broker, RD Host session, RD Gateway
```

I've set up a round-robin dns (called rd.mycompany.local) for the SVRDS1, SVRDS2 and SVRDS3.

This round-robin name is set up in broker HA round-robin name.

If I log on externally via webaccess (I see that the round-robin name is used as address), I get an error ... "An authentication error has occurred (Code: 0x607)".

If I change the round-robin name in the broker HA to SVRDS1.mycompany.local, then I log on perfectly fine.

If I change the round-robin name in the broker HA to SVRDS2.mycompany.local or SVRDS3.mycompany.com, then I get the error again ... "An authentication error has occurred (Code: 0x607)".

I'm lost to where to start to look.

Why is it only one of my rd hosts that works with the round-robin dns name?

Why doesn't it work with the round-robin dns name rd.mycompany.com?

Thanks.

Comment: Just to verify then, you do have rd.mycompany.com pointed to all three servers in DNS?  Meaning there are three separate entries in DNS with the same name but pointing to the three IPs of the RDSH servers?  If not, then that is your first problem.

Comment: Yes all three RDSH servers IPs use the same dns (rd.mycompany.comn) in DNS.

Comment: Forgive these trivial questions I'll be asking you, but I think I know what's going on and I just need to confirm before I direct you on how to proceed.  1) Does using rd.mycompany.local in your Remote Desktop Connection log you on to the farm?  If yes, great, if not, then we'll address that.  2)  If you're trying to use rd.mycompany.com, do you have a zone for mycompany.com which is different than mycompany.local?  If you don't, resolution is your problem and we can address that too.  Please let me know the answers to these.  I work with RDS all the time so we should be able to fix it.

Comment: ... And the above two questions are asking from the standpoint of you being inside your network, on the LAN.  We'll deal with the WAN/external users after that.

Comment: Answers to these?

Comment: Hi Brad, sry I didn't see your answers till now. Yesterday I wrote in this thread http://tinyurl.com/kcnf34l and I was advised to only have one broker and remove my round-robin. Did that, but still have problems. I'm about to give up and call Microsoft. Here's my network: http://pho.to/5RWyQ. I only have one server in collection SVRDS1. If I use webaccess then I get this error trying to connect “An authentication error occurred (Code: 0×607). Remote computer SVRDS1.mycompany.com.”....

Comment: ... If I remove SVRDS1 from collection and add SVRDS2, then I get this error “An authentication error occurred (Code: 0×607). Remote computer SVRDS2.mycompany.com.” - so the error is on all servers. Any idea? Maybe it's time to call MS.

Comment: Don't call MS yet.  I was going to suggest to use one Broker, and make it separate from the RDSH servers.  Create a separate machine for the broker, then put your 3 RDSH servers back in Round Robin DNS.  Try logging in then let me know.  If I can't help you in the next few steps we'll call MS, but let's try my method first.

Comment: Ok - I've created the round robin called rd.company.com, but I'm unsure where in the RDS setup I tell them to use the round robin? When I had the broker HA, there was a round robin entry there, but I'm unsure where to put it now?

Comment: ... when I use the Webaccess it says "DC1" in the  "Remote Computer" - should this point to the round robin? - and how do I do that :)

Comment: It doesn't necessarily need to point to the Round Robin. You can change that server name too... follow this... http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd759250.aspx also, if you're up to it I can do a remote session and take a look at your setup... let me know and I can call you or you call me... if you're not comfortable the next step would be MS but I'd like to save you that money and headache... LMK...

Comment: It's very kind of you and a great offer - but I'm sure I'm not allowed to do that for my company. I guess the company have to pay MS :) I will let you know the result. Thanks for all you help Brad! :)

Comment: I understand. One last thing... can you try this before you call MS: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/67dfab70-7e10-4e0b-a3c8-63ce776f2355/how-do-i-change-the-url-to-the-remote-web-access-server-in-windows-server-2012?forum=winserverTS                  try going through the 2nd post (1st answer)

Comment: Did you try that last link I sent?  At least try it and let me know, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by calling MS.

They changed CAP and RAP to default values and lowered the security on collection to low.

Furthermore I found out it's only possible to use collection by using webaccess. I thought I could use Remote Desktop App and the broker address as "Computer Address", but that's not possible.